# Xubuntu: audio does not work

Tags: drivers, sound, xubuntu, xfce

I just installed Xfce on an Acer 3000 to bring it back to life (1GB DDR RAM, Sempron 3100+ 1.8GHZ), because it's pretty old. The first thing I did after I installed it was setting up the wifi, but then when I tried to test the sound it did not work.

I tried to search for the driver but did not know what to do or even where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Aspire_3000_ZL5), I would suggest:

```
sudo mousepad /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
```

add the following at the end: `options snd-intel8x0 index=0`
Comment out other lines (with `#`) mentioning snd-intel8x0 if present.
Then, do the following:

```
sudo amixer set Master 90% unmute
sudo amixer set PCM 90% unmute
sudo alsactl store
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question but i tried what you said exacmy i opened modprobe as root via terminal and i added option snd-intel8x0 index=0 and wrote sudo amixer set Master 90% unmute but it tell me amixer: Mixer attach default error: No such file or directory
and for sudo amixer set PCM 90% unmute it say : 
amixer: Mixer attach default error: No such file or directory
and for sudo alsactl store : 
alsactl: save_state:1590: No soundcards found...
i tried to install realtek but the sound didnt work so please help !

Comment: you might have to reboot after the modprobe.conf changes, before doing the amixer stuff

Comment: already did  that